# Using Search After without Index Sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch 6.2.4 and currently using Scroll to deal with queries that returns more than 10000 documents, since most of the queries return less (90%) and involve real time usage building scroll is inefficient so I consider to start use the Search After feature.

I noticed that in the example in [Search After Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) that a sort is used and if I understand correctly it will be used in every query , will elastic order the results every time again and again? this can have a huge implication on performance.

I read about the [Sorted Index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-sorting-elasticsearch-6-0), can this solve my problem since the shard will always be sorted? 
Is there any reason to use search after without Sort Index?